# How to call C++ ".so" from PHP

Tags: php, c++

I have created a sample ".so" file using C++, which takes two inputs as parameter and return an integer as below.

```
int calc ( int a , int b ) {

return ( a + b );

}
```

I need to call this "calc" method in PHP and display it. I searched and found "Zend Engine" could help, but I could get any simple samples to try. 
Is Zend engine, the only way to do this or is there any other ways to to call C++ ".so" from PHP.

**Update:**

I have used PHP-CPP for this case.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-php-extension-development-via-php-cpp/), and I created a ".so" and I could call the function in the ".so" from a test php file from command line. But I copied the same testSkeleton.hph" file to "/var/www" folder and ran from browser, in this case it is not invoking the function from the ".so" file.

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?  I have the same requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You would write a PHP Extension, which implements your functions directly or wraps the calls to other C/C++ libraries.

Some pointers on "How to get started with PHP Extensions writing":

- http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/
- http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-php-extension-development-via-php-cpp/
- http://www.php-cpp.com/

--

Note: basic calculation functions are already implemented :)

More advanced math stuff, too: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.math.php

```
<?php
function add($a, $b)
{
    return $a + $b;
}
echo add(5, 10);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,the above example is just for a sample. My intention is to call a C++ ".so" from PHP.

Comment: I have followed the steps here <http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-php-extension-development-via-php-cpp/ and it works if I give "php testSkeleton.php", but I couldnt call the same from browser using apache. What steps should I follow to call same test.php from server?

Comment: Congrats! Seems to work on CLI. Getting it to run in the browser is just a configuration issue. It's often that there are multiple php.ini's, one for CLI, one for web. Make sure, that the extension is loaded in the right php.ini. You can find out the php.ini used, by calling a file with phpinfo() in it, from your browser.

Comment: Thanks, I have upadted the question for more details. I will try it.

Comment: I have copied the skeleton.ini into "apache2/conf.d/" also added "extension=skeleton.so" in "php.ini". still I couldnt load from browser. What would be the problem?

Comment: Please copy your PHP extension into the /php/ext folder.